# C# implementation of FNV Hash

Tags: c#, .net, hash, fnv

I have had numerous cases where I need access to a decent hashing algorithm in C#, from overriding `GetHashCode` to performing quick comparisons/lookups against data.

I have found the FNV hash to be a really easy/good/quick hash algorithm. However, I have never seen a good example of a C# implementation.

The core of the FNV-1a hash algorithm is as follows:

```
 hash = OFFSET_BASIS
 foreach (object value in object) 
 {
     hash = hash ^ value.GetHashCode()
     hash = hash * FNV_PRIME
 }
```

So, when I override `GetHashCode` for a class I end up doing something like:

```
public static class FNVConstants
{
    public static readonly int OffsetBasis = unchecked((int)2166136261);
    public static readonly int Prime = 16777619;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = Constants.FNVConstants.OffsetBasis;
    hash = (hash ^ EntityId.GetHashCode()) * Constants.FNVConstants.Prime;
    hash = (hash ^ FromDate.GetHashCode()) * Constants.FNVConstants.Prime;
    hash = (hash ^ ToDate.GetHashCode()) * Constants.FNVConstants.Prime;
    return hash;
}
```

What do people think of this?

Comment: It looks fine to me... you shoudl just close `hash ^ x` in brackets - e.g. `(hash ^ x) * prime` - otherwise the multiplication will be performed first.

Comment: A 2023 answer to this would be to use `HashCode.Combine(EntityId, FromDate, ToDate)`.

Comment: @dana If the OP is doing an FNV-1a implementation, why would they use a method that uses a different algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why FNV was selected. It does look like the intent is to override `GetHashCode` by combining the hash codes of several properties. This is exactly what `HashCode.Combine` does, without having to worry about the implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add this to your `FNVConstants` class

```
public static int CreateHash(params object[] objs)
{
    return objs.Aggregate(OffsetBasis, (r, o) => (r ^ o.GetHashCode()) * Prime);
}
```

Then call it like

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return FNVConstants.CreateHash(EntityId, FromDate, ToDate);
}
```

Comment: nice. I never thought of using Linq for something like that, but it makes perfect sense. Small, concise. :) Thanks

Comment: GetHashCode should never allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: Huh? Where does it ever allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: @Keith The `params` will result in a heap allocation for the array.

Comment: FNV collects octets/bytes, not hashcodes (ints). I wonder if that makes a difference for hashtables, if for example, `EntityId` goes up from 1 to well above 255. FYI I've doing the same.

Comment: This will also allocate for the `Aggregate` call, and (potentially) for the lambda expression. While this is nice and succinct, if performance matters in your scenario it's worth unrolling the loop and writing a few extra lines of code to avoid allocations.